# Split line on comma but not comma within quotes?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, parsing, split

I have an input file whose head looks like this:

```
AdditionalCookout.create!([
  {day_id: 275, cookout_id: 71, description: "Sample text, that, is ,driving , me, crazy"},
  {day_id: 275, cookout_id: 87, description: nil},
  {day_id: 276, cookout_id: 71, description: nil},
  {day_id: 276, cookout_id: 87, description: nil},
  {day_id: 277, cookout_id: 92, description: nil},
  {day_id: 277, cookout_id: 71, description: nil},
```

I am trying parse each line into it's own object. However, I can't split on commas because some of the descriptions have commas within them..

Tried these two regex lines from the StackOverflow posts I could find:

```
re.split(r', (?=(?:"[^"]*?(?: [^"]*)*))|, (?=[^",]+(?:,|$))', content[x])
```

And:

```
[y.strip() for y in content[x].split(''',(?=(?:[^'"]|'[^']*'|"[^"]*")*$)''')]
```

However.. they both output

```
['{day_id: 275', 'cookout_id: 71, description: "Feeling ambitious? If you really want to exhaust yourself today, consider adding some additional stationary cardio."},']

Turns into:
day_id: 275
cookout_id: 71, description: "Feeling ambitious? If you really want to exhaust yourself today, consider adding some additional stationary cardio.",
```

Any ideas how I can fix this so it correctly splits each line into three separate sections instead of just two? Thanks

Comment: It's unclear to me what you mean by "object" here.  Are you trying to create a list of python dictionaries?

Comment: @DavidC Yup! It looks like Brad's solution will get me there with a little messing around though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using PyYAML to parse it.  Worked from me on your example.   https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyYAML.  Then you can avoid the regex headache.

```
import yaml
yaml.load('{day_id: 275, cookout_id: 71, description: "Sample text, that, is,driving , me, crazy"}')
{'cookout_id': 71,
 'day_id': 275,
 'description': 'Sample text, that, is,driving , me, crazy'}
```

Comment: excellent answer! you can also apply it on the list of dictionarties, it works. Well, maybe it's because input file _was_ yaml. But whatever.

Comment: Awesome! I'm reading the file line by line since there are many classes like "AdditionalCookout" embedded within that have their own lists of dictionaries.. but this will get the job done with a little messing around! Thanks =D

Comment: Point taken @Jean-FrançoisFabre.